# Unable to install Python and GDAL (DLL load failed)

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to install GDAL and Python on my Windows 7 workstation.

- Python-version: 2.6.6
- Gdal 1.8
- (Visual Visual C++ Studio 2010 Express)

I followed the instructions at http://ucsb.pbworks.com/w/page/1936549/Using-GDAL-with-Python and added PYTHONPATH and the GDAL_DATA to my systems environment variables. Furthermore I modified my PATH variable by adding the GDAL binaries folder.

The GDAL Python bindings I downloaded from: http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-8-mapserver-5-6.zip

"**from osgeo import gdal**" causes the following error-message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Thanks in advance,
Martwig

Comment: Are you sure that those gdal python bindings are built with the same version of python and compiler as your python binary? (gdal's python bindings are swig-based, so they're compiled C extensions, not just python source files) Also, did you install gdal from the same source as the gdal python bindings you mentioned?

Comment: I downloaded Python from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/. And yes, I got gdal from the same source. Both, gdal and the bindings, are compiled with Visual Studio 2010 but I did not find out with which compiler Python 2.6.6 was build...

Comment: I solved the problem by installing the MSVC2008-compiled versions of gdal and the gdal-python bindings from http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/. Furthermore I had to remove a backslash in my environment variables ("c:/Program Files/GDAL" instead of "c:/Program Files/GDAL/").

Comment: The Best Solution in my case was switching from **WINDOWS** to Linux. - Because, I struggled with this problem for long time, moreover I found other problems relating to this. Instead of wasting time, It will be much productive to just switch OS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To successfully load GDAL from python in Windows 7, I follow these steps, which should be quite generic:

1. Install python of your choosing, I used v2.7.2 x64 downloaded from the official website
2. Run python from command line to determine the compiler version used to build python (mine shows this message: `Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`)
3. Download the corresponding SDK from this link: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php. Select the correct package for your python (if using the above configuration, then `MSVC2008 x64 release` link should be selected).
4. From  the subpage, download the following:

   - GDAL core components
   - Python bindings
5. Install GDAL core components, add the installation dir to path, and add new environment variable 'GDAL_DATA' pointing to data subdirectory of GDAL installation.
6. Install python bindings
7. You should be profiting from them by now :)

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm! Basically, it is VERY IMPORTANT, to match the compiler version of Python, the Python binding and the GDAL Core package. In my case, I downloaded version 1600 of Python binding and GDAL core package because they were the latest at this moment (08/2014). However, the compiling version of my Python was 1500.

Additionally, I confused architectures: My laptop is a 64 bits machine, HOWEVER, my Python version is 32 bits. So I had to find Python binding packages + GDAL core packages for Win 32 bits architecture AND compiling version 1500. Both things.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: @iamgin makes a good point. Also, [that I know of](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/), there are at least three (maybe more?) environment variables that need attention: `PATH` (`;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL`), `GDAL_DATA` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data`), and `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins`). These values may be different depending on your version of Windows and whether you changed any settings when you installed GDAL, so double-check that these disk addresses are valid before proceeding.

Comment: The `dyndns.org` link does not work anymore, the site has moved to [gisinternals.com](http://www.gisinternals.com/)

Comment: Fixed the link in the answer

Comment: How do you know what release to choose?  There is 1500, 1600, 1700 and so on.  But nothing in the Python version indicate which release to choose.

Comment: Have you checked your python build version by executing `python` from the command line? Read step no. 2. That said, I haven't been on Windows for quite some time, so things might have changed..

Answer (score 10):

The step by step procedure is great. But I had the same issue.

This was caused because my `PATH` variable has other paths where a same named `dll` was used. If you put the `c:\program files\gdal` before the other paths in `PATH`, it works fine!

Comment: This worked for me too, on Windows XP, after following the instructions here http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/docs/gdal_win.pdf

Comment: Worked on win7x32 with Python 2.7 and [GDAL 9.1 + Python bindings from gisinternals.com](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1500-gdal-1-9-mapserver-6-2.zip)

Answer (score 4):

After searching and making many steps from the above answers with no result,  i finally got install to Win7 gdal by using the installer from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Just scroll down the page and find GDAL section and get your version installer.

Answer (score 3):

**solution for python 3.4, v.1600, Windows 10**

make sure what your python version is

```
python -v
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

so here you see that it's v.1600 and 32 bit. Then go here

http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1600-gdal-mapserver.zip

**and download:**

1. gdal-201-1600-core.msi
2. GDAL-2.1.0.win32-py3.4.msi
3. Install these msi files

a. then **make sure you DON'T GET OSGEO4W installed** anywhere (just remove the folder completely if you got it installed).

b. go and edit your environment vars and include in PATH: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL; 
**(include in the beginning!)**

c. restart your python / virtualenv and IDE.

**You should get everything working at this point**

there are also bindings for python 2.7, 3.3, 3.1, other releases http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php

Answer (score 2):

I successfully installed gdal on 32 bit Windows from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal. I solved the "side by side" DLL error by installing this [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Add the GDAL core folder path to your PYTHONPATH variable
- If using PyDev in Eclipse, force the global PATH variable to be include it using the PyDev interpreters section. You can also set PYTHONPATH here.

I got rid of this error after doing this. Funny thing was, calling that line that throws the import exception in a Python interactive shell worked before. Maybe we're all using PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to add the environment variables PATH, GDAL_DATA and GDAL_DRIVER_PATH (all three of them) to System variables NOT user variables for "your username".