# install of GDAL failed for kartograph.py - DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, load, gdal, kartograph

There is a very [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009506/unable-to-install-python-and-gdal-dll-load-failed/16217788#16217788) but solutions there didn't helped me.

I am trying to install and run [kartograpgh.py](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/install-windows.html) tests from installation, and it breaks like this =>

```
C:\tests-kartograph>run_tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tests-kartograph\run_tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kartograph import Kartograph
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\kartograph\_
_init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kartograph import Kartograph
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\kartograph\k
artograph.py", line 8, in <module>
    from map import Map
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 3, in <module>
    from maplayer import MapLayer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
aplayer.py", line 2, in <module>
    from layersource import handle_layer_source
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\kartograph\l
ayersource\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from shplayer import ShapefileLayer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\kartograph\l
ayersource\shplayer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from osgeo.osr import SpatialReference
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_impor
t_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se encontr¾ el proceso especificado.
```

I managed to install all dependent libraries, and also kartograph.py. But as soon as I run the tests provided with kartograph.py i get the error above.

My python version is:

```
C:\tests-kartograph>python
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I followed the solutions provided in the similar topic I mentioned above:

I have set both environment variables, also taking care of writing it ahead in the 'path' variable. The version of the GDAL core and its python binaries I have installed are:

- gdal-19-1500-core.msi GDAL
- GDAL-1.9.2.win32-py2.7.msi

And I also tried the core 'gdal-19-1600-core.msi', since i wasn't 100% sure the GDAL core I need, does't seem trivial to me this installation.

I have tried the installation of osgeo4w, which installs GDAL by its own, but it failed, so i don't have it installed right now. i am afraid that this left some kind of registration that would make my actual installation of GDAL and its DLL not being found by the execution of kartograph.py which calls gdal modules.

Help it's really appreciated, especially tips of how to track or locate the real problem :)

Comment: I find this by far the most annoying problem with GDAL, every once in a while you run into it with no clues on what the problem is. Its been discussed in the mailing list as well, maybe you can find some tips there:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-ImportError-when-importing-gdal-module-with-python-2-7-on-Windows-7-64-bit-td5006198.html

Comment: Well, it's not magic, either you have installed it properly and have set the proper environment variables or you haven't. If it's complaining about a missing DLL, your path to the GDAL utilities is not on the Python path or is incorrect. If you can't find the utilities on the command line, the path is missing from your PATH, or incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named gdal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500176/importerror-no-module-named-gdal)