# ImportError: No module named gdal

Tags: python, command-line, gdal

My GDAL is showing strange behaviour when I try to use ".py" functions from the command line:

**1.** For example, when I run `gdalinfo --version`, I get the standard response:

```
GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16
```

**2.** Also when I run `gdalwarp`, I get the standard response showing me the flags and everything.

**3. Problem:**
However, when I run gdal functions with a .py extension, for example `gdal_polygonize.py`, I get the following:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "C:\OSGeoW64\bin\gdal_polygonize.py", line 36, in <module>
    import gdal, ogr, osr
ImportError: No module named gdal
```

I checked my Path variable, reinstalled python and gdal, but nothing worked.
When I run the `gdal_polygonize.py` function from my QGIS it works. I just can`t use it from my command line.

Comment: make sure your PYTHONPATH is set to the place you installed the library.

Comment: @Serbitar : I guess you mean the folder that contains the `gdal_polygonize.py` function? In my case thats C:\OSGeo4W64\bin, but it´s still not working.

Comment: try printing out `sys.path` and check whether gdal resides there

Comment: @samera : sys.path returns a couple of directories and also "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin"

Comment: No I mean the folder that contains the gdal library.

Comment: @Serbitar : on windows that would for example be: "C:\gdalwin32-1.5\bin" right? Or am I mixing somehting up?

Comment: could be the case. I have actually no idea what gdal is

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two parts to GDAL: the GDAL utilities (`gdalinfo`, `gdalwarp`, etc.) and the GDAL Python Bindings (when you call `from osgeo import gdal` from within a Python script.). The two can be (or could be in the past) installed separately.

The fact that you "see" `gdalwarp` on the command line means that you have the location of the utilities on your PATH (environment variables). Some of the utilities are self-contained, some require the Python bindings (notably those that require calling a .py file). In order for the Python bindings to work, GDAL has to be on the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Find the GDAL folder (will contain `gdalwarp`, for instance). Find the `osgeo` folder in Python's `Lib/site-packages`. Add both of these locations to PATH and PYTHONPATH. You should now be able to `from osgeo import gdal` in a fresh Python shell.

If you cannot, either you are missing some files in those locations (bad install), or you have not specified the path correctly / set the right environment variables. There's no other magic involved, it's either installed and linked correctly, or you did something wrong.

Note that for environment variables to be set and working, you need to "Apply/OK" the environement variables window(s), and also start a fresh command prompt / Python shell.

Answer (score -4):

make sure you install the conda version of gdal.  I never really got gdal to work properly until I installed it from conda.  Make sure you have the anaconda python distribution.  https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: Conda is only one of many choices, and its not the standard (PyPy repos [pip etc] are the standard). The pip version works just fine.