# GDAL command not found with CMD

Tags: python, cmd, gdal

I installed Anaconda3 that comes with python version 2.7.12 and GDAL version 2.1.0.

The path file for the GDAL scripts are set as a user variable and system variable under Path. However, when i type the following:

```
python gdal_merge.py
```

I get the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'gdal_merge.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named gdal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500176/importerror-no-module-named-gdal)

Comment: Clearly you either set the wrong path, or set it in the wrong environement variable. No magic here. The directory where the utilities live need to be in your PATH, Once that is done you can do `gdal_merge.py` directly, rather than `python gdal_merge.py`