# Why "import shapely" and "import gdal" do not work together?

Tags: python, gdal, shapely

My code needs both of these libraries but when I import them like that:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
import gdal
```

I get an error saying that gdal can not be imported. Everything works well when I run them separately. 
I would be thankful for any help. P.S. I am using Python 3.6

Comment: Do you have `gdal` installed?

Comment: Show the complete Traceback

Comment: Yes. And the code works when I write it without shapely.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-", line 12, in <module>
    import gdal
  File "-", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "-", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "-", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "-", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "-", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: What happens if you use simply `import shapely` and `import gdal`? Names go by default only in their module namespace for a reason...

Comment: It seems like everything works well in that way. The new problem is that I do not understand why :/. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Same problem here, ```from shapely.geometry.base import BaseGeometry; from osgeo import gdal``` breaks because it cannot find `_gdal`, but swapping the import order works. Seems related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500176/importerror-no-module-named-gdal