# Problem installing the GDAL package | Python 2

Tags: anaconda, spyder, arcgis, gdal, osgeo

I use anaconda with Python 2.7.15 [[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32]

There is also anaconda with Python 3.6.5 [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32] running on my computer together with ArcGIS Pro

On the Python 2.7.15 I tried to install the GDAL package.
When I run:

**from osgeo import gdal**

I get error:

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

Anyone have a good idea?

Comment: What command did you use to install gdal?

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge gdal

Comment: Well, that's what I imagined. By using conda-forge you broke your Anaconda installation because conda-forge packages are incompatible with the default ones. Now you need to reinstall Anaconda and simply use `conda install gdal`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500176/importerror-no-module-named-gdal/42093733#42093733; there are only so many things that can go wrong...