# When configuring Geodjango, gdal1.10 and python3.3 are incompatible on Windows7

Tags: python, django, postgis, gdal, geodjango

I am using Windows7 to develop a GeoDjango app, my Python version is 3.3. Following the steps from Django documentation, I installed Postgresql9.1 and Postgis extension. Then when I am installing gdal library, there is a problem. I install the gdal from

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal
```

which it says it has all the required files. But for me, I can not correctly set it up. I test it with

`from django.contrib.gis import gdal`

and the following errors prompt out:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__in
it__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Program Files\python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driv
er.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as capi
  File "C:\Program Files\python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prot
otypes\ds.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import lgdal
  File "C:\Program Files\python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libg
dal.py", line 47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\python33\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__

    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application。
>>>
```

So I check the file of libgdal.py in python3.3, and I find there is no lib name for gdal1.10, as from the following code:

```
elif os.name == 'nt':
    # Windows NT shared libraries
    lib_names = ['gdal19', 'gdal18', 'gdal17', 'gdal16', 'gdal15']
```

so I change it to

```
elif os.name == 'nt':
    # Windows NT shared libraries
    lib_names = ['gdal110', 'gdal19', 'gdal18', 'gdal17', 'gdal16', 'gdal15']
```

why I did this is because I find the gdal installed a 'gdal110.dll' file within my python site-package folder.

```
C:\Program Files\python33\Lib\site-packages\osgeo
```

However, this modification doesn't work either.

Then I tried to add this line to my settings.py of Django.

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\Program Files\python33\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal110.dll'
```

it still does not work, the error message was as before.

Can anyone point me a way out?

Comment: @cgohlke I actually deleted OSGeo4W installed folder already, is there any way to trace the conflict and any legacy files that I did not find? I actually also tried to delete the folders installed by lfd...pythonlibs, and reinstall OSGeo4W, but the same error message still.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has settled, I used the accepted answer from

[Unable to install Python and GDAL (DLL load failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009506/unable-to-install-python-and-gdal-dll-load-failed)

and it workds, what I did before this, is to rename my OSGeo4W folder(i.e. delete them). Now Django is able to find gdal from django.contrib.gis.

Comment: worked for me, I had OSGeo4W in my C drive already and it was crashing ....